# "Class App\Repositories\TodoInterface does not exist" Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to implement repositories in my application structure.

I cannot find the problem here. I get the following error message:

ReflectionException
Class App\Repositories\TodoInterface does not exist

### My folder structure is as follows:

```
  ->app
    ->Repositories
         ->TodoInterface.php
         ->EloquentTodo.php
```

### My TodoInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

interface TodoInterface {

public function getAll();

}
```

### My EloquentTodo.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Todo;
class EloquentTodo implements TodoInterface
{
/**
 * @var Todo
 */
private $model;
/**
 * EloquentTodo constructor.
 * @param Todo $model
 */
public function __construct(Todo $model)
{
    $this->model = $model;
}
public function getAll()
{
    return $this->model->all();
}   
}
```

### My AppServiceProvide.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Repositories\EloquentTodo;
use App\Repositories\TodoInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(
            TodoInterface::class,
            EloquentTodo::class
        );
}
}
```

### My composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Repositories\\": "app/Repositories/"
    }
},
```

### My TodoController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Repositories\TodoInterface;

class TodoController extends Controller
{
//
private $todo;

public function __construct(TodoInterface $todo) {

  $this->todo = $todo;

}

public function getAllTodos() {
  return $this->todo->getAll();
}
}
```

### My Route - web.php

```
Route::get('my-todos','TodoController@getAllTodos');
```

Can somebody please help me.

Comment: I think you need to implements interface

Comment: @Priya In "EloquentTodo.php" implementing the interface .

Comment: Sorry, for my mistake

Comment: you want to do run following command  php artisan config:cache , composer dumpautoload

Comment: @RavindraBhanderi Thank u its working now

Comment: its right then flag up this help full to other

Answer (score 1):

In your EloquentTodo.php add `use App\Repositories\TodoInterface`;

See below

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;
use App\Todo;
use App\Repositories\TodoInterface;
class EloquentTodo implements TodoInterface
{
/**
 * @var Todo
 */
private $model;
/**
 * EloquentTodo constructor.
 * @param Todo $model
 */
public function __construct(Todo $model)
{
    $this->model = $model;
}
public function getAll()
{
    return $this->model->all();
}   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following commands:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
```